# How can implement pdist of matlab using eigen with C++?

Tags: c++, matlab, vectorization, eigen

In Matlab, the `D = pdist(X, Y)` function computes pairwise distances between the two sets of observations X and Y. E.g. Given `X = randu(3, 2), Y = randu(3, 2)`, where each row stores an observation (x, y). Then `pdist` returns a [3 x 3] D matrix in which the (i, j) entry represents the distance between the i-th observation in X and the j-th observation in Y.

I want to imitate this behavior using Eigen with C++.

I naively use a for-loop to iterate every observation in X and compute the pairwise distances between the current observation in X and every observation in Y. The result is a [1 x Y.rows] row vector which is then populated into the i-th row of the D matrix.

I think this implementation is somewhat slow as two iterations of the for-loop are independent, and a vectorization technique may be helpful.

Can some shed me some info to make the implementation faster?

I tried using Eigen's binaryExpr but the result was not expected.

Comment: What do you mean by, *the result was not expected*? Do you mean you did not get the result you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented this function according to your explanation (I assume you want number of observations to be dynamic and this should work for any number of observations N1,N2):

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

const int oDims = 2;

typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, oDims, Eigen::RowMajor> ObservationMatrix;

auto pdist(const ObservationMatrix& X, const ObservationMatrix& Y)
{
    return (X.replicate(1, Y.rows()) - Y.reshaped<Eigen::RowMajor>(1, Y.rows() * oDims).replicate(X.rows(), 1))
           .reshaped<Eigen::RowMajor>(X.rows() * Y.rows(), oDims)
           .rowwise().norm()
           .reshaped<Eigen::RowMajor>(X.rows(), Y.rows());
}

int main() {
    ObservationMatrix X(3, oDims), Y(4, oDims);

    X << 3, 2,
         4, 1,
         0, 5;

    Y << 10, 14,
         12, 17,
         16, 11,
         13, 18;

    Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> result = pdist(X, Y);

    std::cout << result << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if this implementation is faster but if you can share your implementation using for-loops we can check the timings. I have tried to verify it's functionality with MATLAB's pdist function. However, I couldn't find a template of pdist that accepts two matrices X, Y like you have described (https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html). Am I missing something?

Comment: It's pdist2 https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html?s_tid=srchtitle. Either way, thank you!